# Will either a NVIDIA GTX660 or GeForce GTX 760 plug n play with Mac Pro 2009?

Tags: mac-pro, gpu

I've researched but am still unclear whether [NVIDIA GTX660](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0099AOAUI) or [Zotac GeForce GTX 760](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00E9O28DU) will just slot into my [Mac Pro 2009](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP506) without buggering about with power supplies etc.

Comment: Keep you old card in case you ever need to see the screen before boot - troubleshooting, recovery, single user etc. 'Regular' PC graphics cards won't show up until the machine fully boots. After that they should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GTX 760 has two connectors to provide it power.  You will need two adapter cables to go from the Macs 6 pin to the video card 6 pin, as they are different sizes.  [Here is a link to one on Amazon.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002UR1654)

[image]

The 660GTX only has a single power connector, so you will just need one if you went that route.

[Here is a video showing the installation of a GTX 660.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TImpXtGYhGE)

You may want to also consider leaving in the original video card so that you will have the ability to see the screen during boot, or when booting holding Option to select the boot disc.  I installed my original card in the top slot, and have it connected to my monitor via VGA and my upgraded card connected via DVI.  That way I can fairly easily switch between them.  It is not required to do this, but may help you down the road.

Comment: Are there two 6 pins 'sockets' inside? I thought there was just the one from the motherboard to the current videocard? Thanks so much :)

Comment: My 08 came with 2 6-pin cables ready-mounted. I've had a GTX 570 in there with no issues, just to test, but haven't tried anything since

Comment: @felixthehat, this answer, http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130559/101107, shows the two connectors on the motherboard.

Comment: You guys are the best! Buying now, will mark as correct when it's in :)

Comment: OK guys, I bought and installed the 760 fine, but it looks like I can't get a driver for it. I've kept the original 120 card in so 1 monitor is OK, but my main 2560x1600 screen shows at 1080p. Am I screwed? Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: 10.10.1 - yosemite

Comment: @FlyingTrashcan - disregard, I tried a new DisplayPort cable and it works great, thanks again!

Comment: @felixthehat - I read elsewhere (e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130485/powering-a-graphics-card-in-a-mac-pro-2008/130559#130559) that the GTX 760 has two power connectors, one 6- and one 8-pin. Does yours, too? Did you connect each to one of the connectors on the motherboard then? Or did you use a single connector on the board with a Y-cable?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmannyeah I got it working with 2 x 6 pins, here's the cable I got from amazon: Apple Mac Pro or G5 mini pci-e 6pin to pci-e 6pin video card power cable 922-7128 922-8446
http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B002NPZSQ6 and